# Java: string.replace doesnt support variables?

Tags: java, string, replace, indexof

When I use :

```
mString = mString.replace(" hello 123 everyone", "Yo");
```

It works fine. But if I use a mix of integer and strings and `" "` and then printLn it shows same output but it won't replace! Same thing with `indexOf`, if I use to many like " " + variable + more stuff, it won't find it.

The output is identical, this must be a bug in Java.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "<h3>Fredag 20 april</h3>";
    int day = 20;   

    System.out.println(s);

    s = s.replace(" " + day, "hello!");

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Output:

```
<h3>Fredag 20 april</h3>
<h3>Fredaghello! april</h3>
```

Working for me!

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying that this doesn't work?

```
String mString = " hello 123 everyone";<br>
mString = mString.replace(" " + "hello " + 123 + " everyone", "Yo");<br>
System.out.println(mString);
```

Make sure you don't have any extra space on the original string.